# How can i add add percentage fees to the product page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

We have a drop-shipping business which we get products from our partner API as a searching results with original prices .

We want to add percentage fees "import duties, VAT , handling fee" immediately to the product price when the customer click on one of the results to open the product page .

so the customer see the final price including everything in the product page "not in the checkout page"

We are using Magento 1.9.2 .

Any solutions please :) ?